# Latest version of gradle can't be found

Tags: android, gradle

The latest version of Gradle is 2.14.1, right? Therefore, I have this:

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1'
    }
}
```

But Android studio says it can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [version of the Android Gradle Build tool](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view) is completely independent of [Gradle](https://gradle.org/gradle-download/).

For example, yes, the [recommended Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions) is <strike>`2.14.1` or higher, but the latest stable Android Gradle Build tool is `2.2.2`</strike>

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

---

**EDIT** (Mar. 2017) versions are now `3.3` or higher & build tool `2.3`

Comment: See the links of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have misunderstood about `Gradle` and `Android Gradle Build Tools`.

In `gradle-wrapper.properties`, you can set the version about the `Gradle`; last `2.14.1`

But in `build.gradle`, you set the `Android Gradle Build tool`; last `2.1.2`

They are not the same thing.