# Which version of android gradle plugin i can use with gradle 2.14?

Tags: android, gradle

I found a table here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility but it has no entry for gradle 2.14. I am trying to build an app without an IDE with gradle

Comment: call `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latest version of gradle can't be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886661/latest-version-of-gradle-cant-be-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it has no entry for gradle 2.14

Do not use Gradle 2.14. Use Gradle 2.14.1. If Gradle issues a patch level release, that's probably due to a critical bug.

Then, you are covered by the last row in the table, simulated below because Stack Overflow does not like teh tabelz:

```
Android Gradle Plugin   Requires Gradle
         2.1.3+            2.14.1+
```

So, if you want to use Gradle 2.14.1, use version 2.1.3 or higher of the Android Plugin for Gradle.