# Android Studio error on running standard java project with offline gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I use `Android Studio 2.2` and `Gradle` in *offline mode*. The value of `Gradle Home` is `/path/to/gradle/gradle-2.14.1`. I can run Android project but now I want to run a Java standard class to test some Java code before using them in Android project. So I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196451/1043882). But when I run class, I got an error like this:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'demo'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
 Required by:
     :demo:unspecified
  > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2 available for  offline mode.
```

Also here is content of `build.gradle` of Java library:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

How I can solve this problem? (I do not want to use another IDE or enabling online mode for Gradle)

Comment: @cricket_007 right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2`...

And that requires internet. The package `gradle-2.14.1` is not the same thing, as [that is Gradle itself, and not the Android Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38886683/2308683).

Though, it is not clear why you have applied that plugin on a standard Java module.

All you need is

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

---

In other words, Gradle simply builds Android code. It's not related to Android in anyway other than that, and you can run Java projects independent of Android if you set it up correctly.

[Gradle - Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

---

For example,

**`java-code/build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

test {
    testLogging {
        // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
        events 'passed'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**`app/build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
evaluationDependsOn(':java-code')

...

dependencies {
    compile project(":java-code")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    ...
}
```

**`settings.gradle`**

```
include ':app', ':java-code'
```

Comment: Yes,it was amazing for me. But why Android Studio can run Android projects?

Comment: Did you just ask why the IDE for making Android projects can run them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I have two questions: 1- Where I have to add `apply plugin: 'java'`? 2- Why Android studio want to use different versions of `Gradle` for running Android projects and `Java`?

Comment: It doesn't use different versions. You have applied a different plugin. In one of the `build.gradle` files, you have `apply plugin: 'android'` at the very top (or at least should)

Comment: I can see `apply plugin: 'java'` in `build.gradle` of  library.